# Having trouble showing that ${d^n\over dx^n}(af(x) + bg(x))=$ $af^n(x) + bg^n(x))$?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, derivatives, proof-writing

How do I show that for any $f$, $g$ that are differentiable for any number $n \in \mathbb N$ and for any $a, b \in \mathbb R$

${d^n\over dx^n}(af(x) + bg(x))=$ $af^n(x) + bg^n(x)$

I don't know how to approach this problem. Should I try to split up $d^n\over dx^n$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hints:

- Try to show the result for $n=1$ first. Then you can apply another derivative to get the case $n=2$, and so on.
- $\frac{d}{dx} (a f(x)) = a \frac{d}{dx} f(x)$
- $\frac{d}{dx}(h_1(x) + h_2(x)) = \frac{d}{dx}(h_1(x)) + \frac{d}{dx}(h_2(x))$
- Note that $f^n$ in your post denotes the $n$th derivative of $f$ (sometimes denoted $f^{(n)}$), not the $n$th power of $f$.

Comment: Your last point cleared up everything! I thought $f^n$ meant the $n^{th}$ power of f. Thanks!